# How can I find the natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $a+b<2021$

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

I am trying to solve the inequality $a + b <2021$, where $1\leqslant a \leqslant 2023$ and $1\leqslant b \leqslant 2023$, $a$ and $b$ are integer numbers, $a \neq b$. I tried

- with $a = 1$, then $b\in \{2, 3, \ldots, 2019\}$, there are 2018 numbers.
- with $a = 2$, then $b\in \{1, 3, 4, \ldots, 2018\}$ , there are 2017 numbers.
- $a = 2019$, then $b=1$.

Thus, I have $1 + 2 + 3 + \cdots + 2018=2037171$

Comment: When you were counting in your question, on the LHS, $a$ increases from $1$ to $2019$; on the RHS and in your final conclusion, the numbers of possible $b$s decrease from $2018$ to $1$. The two sides don't match somewhere in the middle, so you should look into the details.

Comment: @peterwhy Thank you. $1+2+3+\cdots+2018=2037171.$

Comment: Also, your last comment is wrong. It will not be $1+2+3.....2018$. For any value of $a$ in the inequality, we get $b<2021-a$. So, $b$ can take all integral values from $1$ to $2021-a-1 = 2020-a$. However, it cannot take $a$ if $a\le 1010$. So, you have the number of solutions $2018+2017... +1009$ for $a$ from $1$ to $1010$. For $a$ from $1011$ to $2019$, how have $1009+1008+1007...+2+1$ solutions.

Comment: You are not trying to find $a$ and $b$, you are trying to count how many pairs there are.  To find some you can just say $a=1, b=2$.  Please make clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: See the comments that I left, following the answer of Salmon Fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is short by $1009$. First I show how your solution can be proven wrong easily, and then I show how to find the correct solution:

You write the no. of values $b$ can take when $a=1$, $a =2$, .... $a = 2019$, and you add them up. You say it's equal to $1+2+3...+2018$. However, initially, you added $2019$ numbers, but now you're adding only $2018$ numbers. So, there is a mistake in your answer.

---

$$a+b < 2021$$$$b<2021-a$$Since $a,b \in \Bbb Z$
$$b \le 2020-a$$ We also know $b \ge 1$. So, $b$ can take all values from $1$ to $2020-a$ except $a$ if $a \le 1010$. However, if $a \ge 1011$, then $b$ can take all values from $1$ to $2020-a$ (since $a = b$ is not possible here).
So, for $a$ from $1$ to $1010$, you have $2019-a$ values for $b$ and for $a$ from $1011$ to $2019$, you have $2020-a$ values for $b$. Thus, the total number of solutions:
$$(2018+2017+...+1010+\color{green}{1009)+(1009}+1008+...+2+1) = \boxed{2038180}$$

---

Slightly easier approach:
Forget that you have $a \neq b$. Then, like the solution above, you get $1 \le b \le 2020-a$. As $a$ goes from $1$ to $2019$, no. of values for $b$ goes from $2019$ to $1$. Hence, you have $2019+2018+...+2+1 = 2039190$ solutions without the constraint $a \neq b$. You will have exactly $1010$ solutions where $a = b$, which correspond to the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ : $(1,1),(2,2),...,(1009,1009), (1010,1010)$. Subtract $1010$ to get the final answer $$2039190 - 1010 = \boxed{2038180}$$

Comment: Nice answer (+1)

Answer (score 2):

**A summation approach:**

We obtain
\begin{align*}
&\color{blue}{|\{1\leq a\ne b\leq 2023|a+b<2023\}|}\\
&\qquad=|\{1\leq a,b\leq 2019|a+b<2021\}|-|\{1\leq a=b\leq 2019|a+b<2021\}|\\
&\qquad=\sum_{{a+b<2021}\atop{1\leq a,b\leq 2019}}1-\sum_{{a+b<2021}\atop{1\leq a=b\leq 2019}}1\\
&\qquad=\sum_{a=1}^{2019}\sum_{b=1}^{2020-a}1-\sum_{{2a<2021}\atop{1\leq a\leq 2019}}1\\
&\qquad=\sum_{a=1}^{2019}(2020-a)-\sum_{1\leq a\leq 1010}1\\
&\qquad=2020\sum_{a=1}^{2019}1-\sum_{a=1}^{2019}a-1010\\
&\qquad=2020\cdot 2019-\frac{1}{2}2019\cdot 2020-1010\\
&\qquad=2018\cdot 1010\\
&\qquad\,\,\color{blue}{=2\,038\,180}
\end{align*}
in accordance with the answer from @DS.

**A generating function approach:**

- First, we find we can replace the conditions
  \begin{align*}
  1\leq a,b\leq 2023\qquad\text{with}\quad a,b\in\mathbb{N}
  \end{align*}
  since we consider
  \begin{align*}
  a+b< 2021
  \end{align*}
  which already covers the wanted upper bounds. So, we want to find
  \begin{align*}
  &\color{blue}{|\{a,b\in\mathbb{N}|a+b<2021, a\neq b\}|}\tag{1}\\
  &\qquad=|\{a,b\in\mathbb{N}|a+b<2021\}|-1010\tag{2}\\
  \end{align*}

  In (2) we already separated the number of equal pairs
  \begin{align*}
  |\{a,b\in\mathbb{N}|a+b<2021, a= b\}|=1010
  \end{align*}
  to make the derivation a bit easier.
- Considering sums $a+b$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{N}$ in terms of generating functions translates as
  \begin{align*}
  \left(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\right)\left(x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\right)=\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\right)^2
  =\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
  Since we want to count all solutions of $a+b<2021$ we need to sum up all coefficients $[x^n]$ of (3) with $n<2021$. In terms of generating functions we can sum up the coefficients by *multiplying* a generating function $A(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ with $\frac{1}{1-x}$, since
  \begin{align*}
  \color{blue}{\frac{1}{1-x}}A(x)=\frac{1}{1-x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\color{blue}{\sum_{k=0}^n a_k}\right)x^n\tag{3}
  \end{align*}
  which can be shown easily using Cauchy multiplication. In order to sum up all coefficients $< 2021$ in (2), we can instead multiply the generating function with $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and extract the coefficient of $x^{2020}$. Using the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of a series we obtain from (2) and (3):
  \begin{align*}
  &\color{blue}{|\{a,b\in\mathbb{N}|a+b<2021, a\neq b\}|}\\
  &\qquad=[x^{2020}]\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\,\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^2}\right)-1010\\
  &\qquad=[x^{2020}]\frac{x^2}{(1-x)^3}-1010\\
  &\qquad=[x^{2018}]\frac{1}{(1-x)^3}-1010\tag{4}\\
  &\qquad=\binom{-3}{2018}-1010\tag{5}\\
  &\qquad\color{blue}{=\binom{2020}{2}-1010=2\,038\,180}\tag{6}
  \end{align*}

*Comment*:

- In (4) we apply the rule $[x^p]x^qA(x)=[x^{p-q}]A(x)$.
- In (5) we use the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)* and select the coefficient $x^{2018}$.
- In (6) we use the binomial identities $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$ and $\binom{p}{q}=\binom{p}{p-q}$.

Comment: (+1) it's nice to see an approach in summation form. Maybe you can also add my first approach in summation form?

Comment: @DS: I've added a generating function approach instead, which might be a bit more interesting.

Answer (score 1):

If $a+b < 2021 \rightarrow a+b \leq 2020$ , now lets define another nonnegative variable $c$ such that $a+b+c =2020$.

It is given that $1 \leq a,b \leq 2023$ and $a \neq b$. Hence , lets write a sequence such that its exponentials are equal to possible values of $a$ and $b$. This is called as [generating functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function).

- $$a=1,2,3,...,2019,2020 \color{red}{\rightarrow} x^1+x^2+x^3+...+x^{2019}+x^{2020}= \frac{x-x^{2021}}{1-x}$$
- $$b=1,2,3,...,2019,2020 \color{red}{\rightarrow} x^1+x^2+x^3+...+x^{2019}+x^{2020}= \frac{x-x^{2021}}{1-x}$$
- $$c=0,1,2...,2020 \color{red}{\rightarrow} 1+ x^1+x^2+x^3+...+x^{2019}+x^{2020}= \frac{1-x^{2021}}{1-x}$$

Now , if we find the coefficient of $x^{2020}$ in the expansion of $$\frac{x-x^{2021}}{1-x} \times \frac{x-x^{2021}}{1-x} \times \frac{1-x^{2021}}{1-x} $$ We can find the all possible solutions for $a+b+c=2020$

However , this expansion will also count such cases :

- $a=1,b=1,c=2018$
- $a=2,b=2,c=2014$
- $a=3,b=3,c=2012$
- ....
- $a=1009,b=1009,c=2$
- $a=1010,b=1010,c=0$

So , the answer is $$[x^{2020}]\bigg(\frac{x-x^{2021}}{1-x} \times \frac{x-x^{2021}}{1-x} \times \frac{1-x^{2021}}{1-x}\bigg) - 1010$$

Comment: I agree that generating functions can be used to solve the problem, but I (still) question the appropriateness of your answer.  Problems such as this one can generally be solved by either generating functions or [Stars and Bars theory](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/), which is also discussed 
[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).  Stars and Bars theory has a much smaller learning curve and for elementary problems of this nature, is easier to apply.  ...see next comment

Comment: For this particular problem, you start with $x_1 + x_2 + c = 2020, ~: ~x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}, ~c \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}}.$  Then, the simple change of variables $~y_1 = x_1 - 1, y_2 = x_2 - 1,~$ yields the Stars and Bars problem in its basic format of $$y_1 + y_2 + c = 2018, ~y_1,y_2,c \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}},$$ which has $~\displaystyle \binom{2018 + 2}{2}~$ solutions.  $~$ From this, you simply subtract the $~1010~$ solutions where $~x_1 = x_2.$

Comment: Given the nature of the original posting, my first instinct would be to present the original poster with an approach that has the easiest learning curve.  It is certainly true that for (much) more complicated Stars and Bars problems, generating functions provides an easier solution, if one confidently knows the theory.  I simply question whether this problem, with this original poster, is the place for generating functions.

Comment: @user2661923 you are totally right.. I will try it firstly from now on..

Comment: @SalmonFish I'm new to generating functions. So, is there any way to calculate the coefficient of $x^{2020}$ in the expression?